Inherit interface and automatically implement the properties
I have a case where I should inherit a class from an interface that will automatically implement without typing the implementation inside the parent class, is it possible?
For example:
public interface IBaseClass
{
    Guid? ID{get;set;}
}

public class BaseClass:IBaseClass
{
    public Guid? ID{get;set;}
}

public class ProductObject:IBaseClass
{
}

So, does the ProductObject automatically include the ID property (without typing the ID implementation inside the class)?

No. It won't compile.

Although C# 8 introduced default interface methods, it didn't do away with the requirement to implement properties defined by interfaces in inheriting classes.

Or did you mean to have ProductObject inherit from BaseClass?

As @JohnathanBarclay said, you should probably just make ProductObject inherit from BaseClass as it also inherits IBaseClass. Failing that, you would probably need to take a look at source generators to implement properties that haven't already been implemented

Some refactoring tools have a feature to automatically create implementations of interfaces.

No, you cannot derive from an interface that declares some properties without explicitly declaring the properties in the derived class.
In your case you will get an error similar to:

error CS0535: 'ProductObject' does not implement interface member
'IBaseClass.ID'

You have 2 valid options:

Derive ProductObject from BaseClass (the class) instead of IBaseClass (the interface):
public class ProductObject : BaseClass
{
}

Deriving from a class will make the property a part of ProductObject.

Declare the property in ProductObject:
public class ProductObject : IBaseClass
{
    public Guid? ID { get; set; }
}



Notes:

C# 8 introduced default interface methods, but these do not apply to properties.
You can use some automatic refactoring tool that will generate the property in the derived class, but the code eventually will have to be there.


There is a way to do it with Roslyn Source Generator. It is able to analyze your code and for example you could add an attribute to search for in analyzer and the generator could generate a partial class of the class with the properties definied by the interface. The generator updates the file, if you setup it correctly.
So after implementing the generator, the class should implement the Attribute you define and be a partial class. So you do not need to implement the properties by hand.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/source-generators-overview
